# Open new window on right, left, top, bottom

Tags: vim

I'm able to open a new empty horizontal window by doing:

```
:new
```

And a vertical one by doing:

```
:vnew
```

The horizontal one is always positioned on the bottom, and the vertical one on the left. How would I open a new horizontal window on top of the existing one, and a new vertical window to the right of the current one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default placement of new windows with the `splitbelow` and `splitright` settings:

To open new horizontal windows below the current one:

```
set splitbelow
```

To open new vertical windows to the right of the current one:

```
set splitright
```

To reverse these settings, simply do `set nosplitbelow` or `set nosplitright`. If new windows open below the current window now, you should probably check if `splitbelow` is set.

More information is available in the documentation:

- [splitbelow](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27splitbelow%27)
- [splitright](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27splitright%27)
- [opening windows](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#opening-window)